# Windows 10 Shows Orange Screen with White Vertical Lines on boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, hyper-v, dell-inspiron, bitlocker

Orange Screen (See picture below) appears on boot after Dell loading screen.

- Dell Inspiron 580 w dual monitors
- Dell Bios is latest version (A07)
- Nvidia GeForce 310 (Driver version 341.95 - latest)
- BitLocker enabled with no TPM
- Hyper-V enabled

Surprisingly, I can key in my BitLocker password at this orange screen and startup Windows... (O_o)\

If I suspend BitLocker this screen does not appear; but after I enabled it, the orange screen comes back again.

I found these messages in Event Log, maybe they will be helpful:

- **(Warning)** The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WPD\0000.
- **(Error)** The required GPU resources could not be accessed. This server cannot run as a RemoteFX host without a GPU. Verify that the GPU is correctly installed.

[image: Orange Screen of Death?!?]

Screenshot of Disk Management

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: Its a driver issue of some sort, strange issue with no clear answers using Google, but as this link shows it could be a bitlocker bug...http://superuser.com/questions/533360/windows-8-shows-orange-screen-with-white-stripes-on-boot

Comment: I can confirm this is not a hardware issue. Firmware/drivers maybe. Still haven't managed to find a solid solution to this. Standard windows...

Comment: What's the model of the machine this is in and what type of disk configuration does it have hardware and software wise? If you can give detail to your Bitlocker setup configuration (e.g. with TPM, etc.), that may be helpful as well. Have you checked your Event Viewer logs for any applicable errors, etc.?

Comment: What display card do you have? nvidia or amd?, i'd suggest you remove the drivers and use install microsoft drivers, this will discard any driver issue, some drivers will not allow certain resolutions to be used with specific hardware, the bitlocker blue text screen might be one of those resolution modes, try this and let us know.

Comment: My Nvidia GeForce 310 display driver is latest version, what other drivers should I check?

Comment: I found this in Event Log: (warning) `The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WPD\0000.` (Error) `The required GPU resources could not be accessed. This server cannot run as a RemoteFX host without a GPU. Verify that the GPU is correctly installed.`

Comment: This has just occurred to me on two separate laptops at the same time. One is a Sony Viao Z2 from 2011 and the other a Dell XPS 15 2014. Completely different set of hardware but both on Win10. This isn't pointing at a hardware or driver problem...

Comment: This same error occurred to me when I tried to install Win 10 off corrupt installation media.

Comment: Could we get a screenshot of Disk Management from after Windows boots?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an OS update, and the OP just stuck (t)his solution in to his question. :/

Comment: If an OS update solved the problem, that was the solution and it should go in an answer.  That doesn't make it off-topic.  However, sticking it in the question sure makes the question unclear.

Comment: @SimplyInk Aside from the community protect (that shouldn't have affected you as you have more than 10 rep) I can't see why you wouldn't be able to post an answer. Give it another shot now, if you have any trouble then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Aug 2016 [Win 10 Anniversary Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history) Solved My Problem

This update fixed my orange screen on BitLocker boot screen.

Beware: Updating took a few restarts and about 2-3 hours on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and am posting for posterity. I  was especially perplexed since I don't use bitlocker (Veracrpyt instead, open source, no one including MSFT will be able to crack the encryption).

Creating a boot from Media Creation Tool to a USB thumb drive and attempting to reinstall gave me this orange white striped screen.

It's not until I used a third party USB boot creator (Rufus in my case, but probably others will do) that everything worked as it should AND I WAS NEVER ASKED FOR A BITLOCKER PASSWORD EXPLICITLY OR INDIRECTLY (orange screen).

I used windows media tool to create an .iso file, then Rufus to create a bootable drive on my USB thumb drive. Be careful which partition scheme you use.

Without thinking about it I chose MBR, which leads to having a non-UEFI legacy boot mode, which later caused an annoyance with Veracrypt.

But if you don't care then MBR will work fine.

I had to convert my MBR partition to GPT to be able to use Veracrypt with a USB rescue drive.

Comment: You had orange lines on your screen due to installing a pre-Anniversary update to Windows 10? You appear to tell us how you reinstalled Windows, not given an answer to the question that was posed, which is asking what the cause of the issue is.