# How can I fix a Bitlocker protected laptop which doesn't have a local admin account that's displaying the orange screen of death

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have a BitLocker protected Win 10 laptop (no TPM, just password) that's suddenly displayed this orange screen with white vertical lines -

[Windows 10 Shows Orange Screen with White Vertical Lines on boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1068366/windows-10-shows-orange-screen-with-white-vertical-lines-on-boot/1101268)

Once at this screen I can only reboot or go to the BitLocker recovery screen. No BIOS or firmware updates were done, but this could have been caused by some recent Windows updates.

The BIOS menu displays and so does the BitLocker recovery screen. Upon entering the BitLocker recovery screen I'm presented with advanced troubleshooting options - none of which I can use as I don't have a local admin account (looks like group policy stripped this out -the laptop is domain joined).

Given that I don't have a local admin account to run commands like "fixmbr" and perform a PC restore I'm pretty stuck - before I nuke the laptop and re-install the OS, I wanted to check if there are any options (I'm thinking something like running a Peter Nordahl boot disk and creating a local admin account)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is no TMP you should be able to boot from a disk (PN, hirens) and try to fix the MBR or add/enable the local administrator account.

Comment: But the laptop is bitlocker protected, so how would a standard Windows boot disk be able to access the hard disk?

Comment: You can mount the volume if you know the bitlocker password. Otherwise, you'll just have to format.

Comment: How does the author do what you suggest, author clearly needs help, explain how to do something if your going to suggest doing it.  This isn't the first time I have provided this type of feedback to one of your questions

Comment: Hirens boot CD supports mounting encrypted volumes. My answer is therefore complete. Disklocker is an independent tool that can do this: https://theevilbit.blogspot.ro/2014/04/using-dislocker-to-mount-bitlocker.html and variations of it are integrated into several Hiren's like disks.

Comment: Thanks guys, Booting using a Windows 10 usb stick worked, popped in the decrypt key and ran a ton of bootrec /fix commands as below http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows                     unfortunately the problem still persists :-(, maybe a hardware error

Comment: Try a clean install. If the OS actually installs without any stop error, there should be no HW problem, not a critical one anyway.

Answer (score -1):

What causes this error?

This issue is still developing and under investigation, but is suspected to be caused by the recent Microsoft Security Update KB3172985

Current workaround:

1. Enter the BitLocker PIN/password blindly on the orange/blue screen. This should bypass the screen temporarily and allow you to log in to Windows.
2. Uninstall the security update (KB3172985) and restart when prompted. It will still have the orange/blue screen at this point.
3. Suspend BitLocker by opening the “BitLocker Drive Encryption” Control Panel applet and clicking “Suspend Protection” and then “Yes” to apply.
4. Check for updates to automatically find and reinstall the security update.
5. Reboot and the BitLocker PIN/password screen should appear normally.

Alternative workaround:

1. If the issue is still present, re-enter the BitLocker PIN/password blindly on the orange/blue screen to boot into Windows.
2. Suspend BitLocker by opening the “BitLocker Drive Encryption” Control Panel applet and clicking “Suspend Protection” and then “Yes” to apply.
3. Open an Administrator Command Prompt by clicking Start, typing “CMD” without quotes, right-clicking the top search result and choosing “Run as administrator.”
4. Then type the following command and click Enter:
   bfsvc.exe %windir%\boot /v
5. Reboot the computer.